# Why is the .map() function not iterating?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, mapping, state

I am trying to iterate through my state via .map(), but the function stops after the first return:

```
private renderEmployeesTable() {
if (this.state.employees) {


  return new Array(this.state.employees).map((_, index) => {



    const employeeId: string | undefined =
      this.state.employees[index]?.employeeId;
    const employeeName: string | null = this.state.employees[index]?.name;
    return (
      <>
        <div className="row">
          <div className="col">
            <p className="rowText">{employeeId}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <p className="rowText">{employeeName}</p>
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <p className="rowText">
              {
                this.state.workingHoursForEveryEmployee.find(
                  (res) => res.employeeId === employeeId
                )?.workingHours
              }
            </p>
          </div>
          <div className="col">
            <p className="rowText">{this.state.hoursToWork}</p>
          </div>
        </div>{" "}
      </>
    );
  });
}
```

}

In the console, index is 0 and doesn't go up.
Do you have any idea, how I could fix this?

Comment: What is the value of `this.state.employees` ?

Comment: Array(4) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, {…} ]
​
0: Object { name: "Holger ´", employeeId: "10001", username: "fae", … }
​
1: Object { name: "Peter Pan", employeeId: "10003", username: "peterp", … }
​
2: Object { name: "J.F. Sebastian", employeeId: "10004", username: "sebastianjf", … }
​
3: Object { name: "asdasdds", employeeId: "3951333362035965801", username: "asdasd", … }
​
length: 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your are creating a new `Array()` which contains only 1 item: an array.

You probably don't need the `new Array()` part, just map `this.state.employees` directly.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create an array that has only `this.state.employees` as an element. If you want to iterate elements with map in `this.state.employees`, use the map function directly.
If you want to create iterables in the form of an Array, use `Array.from()`